# Getting CNAMEAlreadyExists error on AWS CloudFront although CNAME is deleted

Tags: cname, amazon-cloudfront

I have deleted a distribution from AWS CloudFront and trying to create a new distribution using the CNAME that I had used in the deleted distribution. I am now getting `Status Code: 409; Error Code: CNAMEAlreadyExists;`. I am confused because I have just deleted the distribution and I do not have any other distribution in my CloudFront. I am wondering what I am supposed to do to create the distribution again using the older CNAME.

Comment: I figured out my problem. I had to delete the certificate from AWS Certificate Manager and issued a new certificate.

Comment: Are you saying that if you have a distribution using a CNAME with its respective certificate loaded from ACM and you delete the distribution, to be able to use that CNAME again in a new distribution you have to delete the ACM certificate and generate one again?

Comment: sorry for the late response. yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In my case, I've just deleted the old CNAME DNS from my DNS provider which was pointing to the old CloudFront link.

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer. "To correct this, sign in to your DNS provider and remove the existing DNS record, or contact your DNS provider to remove it for you." from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-move

Comment: Yes, this should be marked as the right answer. AWS error message here is opposite of what's happening. What it shoul day is the this domain is pointing to old CF distro domain. That needs to be removed by whoever manages the DNS.

Comment: This is the right answer. In my case I had to go to GoDaddy and delete my CNAME there.